# Object Oriented Approach for C#

Tags: c#, oop

I am exploring this and see if this one make sense. For instance I have 2 abstract objects called: Customer and Tender. The relationship is that one Customer can have many Tenders.

How can I achieve the following on the TestClient app:

1. `customer.InTender[0].ID = ???`

   What method to handle to handle this? Do I need to pass `CustomerID` into `Customer` constructor to achieve this or ... ?
2. If I want to get all tenders for that particular customer should I do this:

   ```
    customer.InTender.Get()
   ```
3. How do I differentiate between All Tender VS All Customer Tender (point 3). I guess it will be like this. One with ID of Customer and the other one without?

   ```
    inTender.Get()
   ```

---

```
public abstract class Customer
{
    protected Int64 id;
    protected string name;

    protected ArrayList tender;

    public abstract ArrayList Tender
    {
       get;
       set;
    }  

    public abstract Int64 ID
    {
       get;
       set;
    }  

    public abstract string Name
    {
       get;
       set;
    }  


    public abstract bool Update();

    public abstract bool Add();

    public abstract bool Delete();
}

public class CorporateCustomer : Customer
{
    public CorporateCustomer ()
    {}

        public override ArrayList Tender
        {
            get
            {
                return tender
            }
            set
            {
                tender = value;
            }
        }   

    public override Int64 ID
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                id = value;
            }
        }

        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }

    public override bool Update()
    {
    return true;
    }

    public override bool Add()
    {
    return true;
    }

    public override bool Delete()
    {
    return true;
    }
}


public abstract class Tender
{
    protected Int64 id;
    protected string name;

    public abstract bool Update();

    public abstract bool Add();

    public abstract bool Delete();

}

public class InTender : Tender
{
    public InTender ()
    {}

        
    public override Int64 ID
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                id = value;
            }
        }

        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }

    public override bool Update()
    {
    return true;
    }

    public override bool Add()
    {
    return true;
    }

    public override bool Delete()
    {
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be irrelevant, but so I can better understand the problem you're trying to solve, what is "Tender" referring to?

Comment: Looks like school assignment.

Comment: Please indent all code an additional 4 spaces to put the whole class in the code box.

Comment: Side note: Please don't use ArrayList.  It's been obsolete for years.  Use List<T>.

Comment: I fixed the indentation, but the code's still a mess.  It just doesn't make any sense to me.  For example, why is there an abstract Tender property when there's a protected field by that name?  This is an ABC, not an interface, so the property should be linked to the field, and probably shouldn't even be virtual.  This is just the first of many problems, including Name being used for both an int and a string.

Comment: Ok, declaring the abstract name property to return an int is definitely a typo, so I fixed it.  I also changed it from "String" to "string", since you should use the native, not CLR, types.

Comment: I'm not going to be able to help here, so I'm deleting my responses and moving on.

Comment: @dewacorp.alliances Your question is very difficult to understand... perhaps you could get someone with stronger English skills to help you ask? If it is clearer, more people will be able to help you with it.

Comment: Sorry. I am trying to understand this OO approach. 
@ph0enix: Tender is referring as running as a Tender (Bid) process. For particular CUstomer will run so many tender response proces.

@Steven Sudit: Thanks for fixing this I am typing without checking the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Don't use ArrayList, it was depreciated as of .net 2.0.  You should use List, IList, or Dictionary.

Also, Customer sure seems like concrete type.  Are you going to have multiple Customer classes that all inherit from it?  If not, drop the Abstract.   Same goes for your other classes.

2) Look up Repository objects and LazyLoading.  Davy Bryon has a good series on building your own DAL.  http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/08/build-your-own-data-access-layer-lazy-loading/

But either the customer should have all of the Tenders right away, or you should have a service that gets them for you.  I'm not in favor of having Entities know about their persistence.

Anyway, the general approach is to have a separate Repository class that has the methods needed to get the data you need.

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers() { .... }
    public List<Tenders> GetTendersForCustomer(Customer customer) { .... }

}
```

Comment: 1) I am starting to use the Abstrac in my classes. I used to code directly on implementation of the class.

2) With the code that you give me, let say if I want to test this class so in myTestApp:

List<Tenders> tenderColl;
CustomerRepository customer = new CustomerRepository ();
tenderColl = customer.GetTenders();

BUT I want to have in such away that:

CorporateCUstomer customer = new Customer(21);
Int64 tenderID = customer.Tender[0].ID; //TenderID of array 1
string tenderName = customer.Tender[0].Name //TenderName of array 1

Comment: You are looking for an ActiveRecord style pattern here.  Traditionally that is bad design because you are mixing responsibilities in your objects.  Single Responsibility is the key.  An object either holds its data, or it know how to persist itself.  Try not to mix the two.  The end result is that you get code that is very hard to test, but also hard to modify -- there is too much stuff going on in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a standard `Tender` class and a standard `Customer` class with a property `List < Tender >`  should suffice. I don't see why you need the abstract classes and the inheritance.

```
class Tender {}

class Customer {
     List < Tender > tenders; // would be null if customer has no tenders
     ....
}
```

Comment: There are possibility that tender could be "PreTender", "PostTender", "InTender"